# tfmini-plus checksum error on raspberry pi

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi3, node-serialport

I had initiated an example for TFMiniplus on Pi - 3. I have installed the tfmnini-plus, serialport, and @serialport/bindings and I have been using the following code:

```
const tfminiplus = require('tfmini-plus')
let path = '/dev/ttyUSB0';
tfminiplus.UART(path, { baudRate: 115200 }).then(async (tfmp) => {
  const distance = await tfmp.distance()
  console.log('distance:', distance)
})
.catch(console.error)
```

I am getting the following error only:
**

```
5a0603000063595900
Error: checksum failed
at checksum (/home/pi/node/node_modules/tfmini-plus/tfmini-plus.js:14:27)
at async Object.distance (/home/pi/node/node_modules/tfmini-plus/tfmini-plus.js:40:18)
at async /home/pi/node/tfmini2.js:6:20
```

**
Package.json is as under:

```
{  
"name": "node",   
"version": "1.0.0",   
"description": "",   
"main": "tfmini2.js",   
"dependencies": {     
    "@serialport/bindings": "^9.0.0",     
    "i2c-bus": "^5.2.0",     
    "serialport": "^9.0.0",     
    "tfmini-plus": "^2.1.0"   
},   "
devDependencies": {},   
"scripts": {     
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"   
},   
"author": "",   
"license": "ISC"
}
```

Any ideas what could possibly be going wrong. Node version 12.18.2 and npm version 6.14.6

Thanks and Regards

Comment: missing a lot of contexts, package.json so we know which version you are using, how are you starting your code, and how you are getting this error (steps to reproduce)

Comment: I have added package.json, the code that I am using is as above in its entirety. I am using the tfmini plus with a usb to uart converter, hence the device /dev/ttyUSB0.